# Finding specs for an Intel integrated GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

I'm trying to find specs for my integrated GPU. lshw gives me some details:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
product: HD Graphics 5300
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: 08
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=3200,1800
resources: irq:51 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff
    ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

But it is not detailed enough. I want to know what clock frequency the
gpu operates under, how many cores it has, how much vram, how to
program it, etc. Such information is easily available for Nvidia
cards, but not for this Intel gpu. So my question is are there linux
command line tools that can query this data or any webpages
containing detailed specs for my gpu?

Comment: Under Windows I would suggest GPU-z https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/ but you should know that integrated graphics uses system RAM so how much VRAM it has is not a relevant figure.

Comment: A search for "intel graphics 5300 specs" will give you a link to that information on the techpowerup site.

Comment: Is techpowerup.com reliable?

Comment: Reliable enough for the info you're looking for.